# Socket IO client custom event not fired after reconnect

Tags: node.js, socket.io

```
var clientSocket = clientIO(`http://serverIP:3000`)
                            .on('connect', () => {
                                //...
                            })
                            .on('disconnect', (reason) => {
                               //..
                            })
                            .on('custom-event', (data) => {
                               //..
                            });
```

I registered my custom event to client socket-io like the code above, it worked fine, but when socket is disconnected then reconnected the custom registered event not fired again, Should I register custom event on reconnect? Or there is a better way to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

In socket.io [client api](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#Event-%E2%80%98connect%E2%80%99) they said you should register event handlers outside of connect, so they are not registered again on reconnection